# Code Error Python : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'set' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code in Python is giving an error of invalid syntax in a simple expression,:

```
mediaa = float(input('Digite sua média anual: '))
recup = {60-(mediaa * 6)} / 4
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arthu/PycharmProjects/projeto-notas/nota-recuperação.py", line 2, in 
    recup = {60-(mediaa * 6)} / 4
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'set' and 'int'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Replace `{ }` by `( )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use { } when you mean ( ).  The curly braces make it into a set, not an integer.

```
recup = (60-(mediaa * 6)) / 4
```

Comment: Thanks man, really apreciate that, sorry if it's a basic doubt, because I'm starting on this wonderful world of Python right now. Thanks a lot man. You're the best!

Comment: Cheers!  Please vote up and accept the answer if it helped you.